# What does "You can only work on so many things at a time" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

From the following context, what does mean this sentence

> You can only work on so many things at a time

It sounds to me like

> The size doesn't matter both when you work on so many things at a time and when you work on one thing at a time

which is contradictory. WIP in this context is work-in-progress.

> You may be thinking that allocating your workload (your capacity)
>       by WIP limits won’t fly because your work items aren’t all the same
>       size. This is an area where size doesn’t really matter because **you can
>       only work on so many things at a time**. It doesn’t matter how big or
>       small something is when you can only truly focus on one thing at a
>       time. It could be as small as a mouse or as big as an elephant (metaphorically
>       speaking). When it’s done, you move on to the next thing.

Comment: It means “there is a limit to how many things you can work on at a time”.  Your ability to multitask is limited.

Answer (score 1):

*So many* in this sort of context, means *a maximum of* - except that it does not specify what that maximum is.

Another (less idiomatic) way of saying it would be: *there is a maximum number of tasks that you can successfully work on at the same time*.

Answer (score 0):

They probably asked you to have fewer tasks in progress, and said it like this, "you need to be working fewer tasks at a time."

Now there are many reasons and arguments for (and against) fewer WIP items, but they are not English language problems.  To ask about those reasons, I suggest you submit a similar question to "The Workplace"